How to fix directory creation issue on wordpress?
I faced the issue on the deployed version of my Wordpress site. When I add/upload images through Wordpress admin panel, shows like this issue below
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2024/11. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
I want to upload images properly through Wordpress admin panel. I am adding
permissions like
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );

but not working

Is its parent directory writable by the server? - what's your answer to that question? How is this problem even related to programming?

You can check directory permissions and set to 755 and for files to 644.
Add below code wp-config.php file
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' ); 

